# 'MySQL server has gone away'

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, xampp

I am using xampp and tried to create some tables using laravel 5 but it will give an error as follows, when I execute 'php artisan migrate' command. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?? I have already changed the max_allowed_packet into 64M.

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

[ErrorException]
PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away

Comment: @RaviHirani thx for the dupe lookup :p

Comment: @Drew: Welcome. It was just a coincidence :D